# Codename One - server build fails

Tags: codenameone

I have an existing Codename One project that has built successfully in the past. I've made changes to the project and the most recent build fails. I went back to the most recent version that DID build, and it NOW fails. So, I went back to the Codename One initializr and created a bare-bones Java App (my IDE is NetBeans). This builds ok. I progressively added my code to the bare-bones App and it fails when I add a fairly simple java file, HHTCrit.java (mentioned in the log below) (I can post if you feel relevant). Any suggestions to progress?

The build error log is large (20,000+ lines). Here are some relevant parts.

```
Tried to start hyperlog but failed: Failed to start hyperlog: Cannot run program "hyp": error=2, No such file or directory

> Task :multiDexListDebug> Task :multiDexListDebug FAILED FAILED
/tmp/build1965224036948247615xxx/MyApp/libs/userClasses.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException/tmp/build1965224036948247615xxx/MyApp/libs/userClasses.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException

FAILURE: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.Build failed with an exception.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':multiDexListDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Error while merging dex archives: 

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':multiDexListDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:207)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$$Lambda$477/1137979299.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':multiDexListDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:207)
```

Comment: I will need that 20k line file to help you. Native build errors are misleading and show the wrong information in the bottom line. Understanding the root cause is often tricky.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, thanks for the reply. Here is a link to the error log. (I hope this is acceptable). https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-NyoyKeYoj4ODh6IGi-OFVh_jBCuTpah/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: I will need a universal link to view the file. If you feel uncomfortable posting such a link here please use our website chat at codenameone.com and I will review it and get back to you. Be sure to include a link to this conversation for context...

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, my mistake, apologies. Here is a new link (accessible to everyone). https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-NyoyKeYoj4ODh6IGi-OFVh_jBCuTpah/view?usp=sharing I'll also post to your website chat.

Comment: I'm guessing this is your error `CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /tmp/build3357956911896100708xxx/MyApp/libs/userClasses.jar:com/stylsy/app/HHTCrit.class`. Make sure you used JDK 11 and not something newer. Also did you define any dependencies in maven?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, thanks. Yes, my JDK was newer (oops!) (I'll switch back). Apologies again.